# printscreen for asp.net mvc 3 jquery plugin?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, pdf-generation

I have been searching for a jquery plugin  or something else to create a pdf from  a screen shot of my asp.net mvc page? is there something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF is pretty hefty standard. You will have hard time finding PDF generation tools for server side languages, but writing a PDF parser for javascript would be really huge. I've never come across anything like this.

Comment: _You will have hard time finding PDF generation tools_ or _You will NOT have hard time finding PDF generation tools_ ? There are some libraries available to generate PDF at server side

Comment: Yeah sure, there are. I didn't say that there aren't. It's just that there are not so many and most of them are commercial due to the complexity of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery Print Preview. You can found example at

https://github.com/etimbo/jquery-print-preview-plugin

Thanks,
-Naren